# Reading High/Low from Pins through RS232

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am new to RS232 and have some confusion about reading the pins. Here is the scenario I am trying to achieve:

There is a motion sensor on a line and when someone passes it, it triggers and sends a signal to a different terminal's IO board - connected through RS232.

I am uncertain of the format the data comes in, but I assume it is an high or low input. But in C# I don't know how to read the actual Pins except for the handshake pins `DTR, RTS and CTS`. More specifically I can listen to the `SerialPort.OnPinChanged` event.

But here is my confusion: Where is the high/low signal being sent to.

I can easily read the data in C#. But I'm not even sure if I want to read the data if it is a simple high/low signal, and definitely not sure if this is a valid option for `RS232` connections. At the moment I am leaning towards No.

Comment: Do you know the communication protocol?  You should be able to use the socket library to read the data, then if you know the protocol you would know the structure to parse the bytes into to handle or read the data being sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick tutorial on RS-232 for you to reference
https://www.codrey.com/embedded-systems/rs232-serial-communication/

"There is a motion sensor on a line and when someone passes it, **it triggers and sends a signal** to a different terminal's IO board - connected through RS232."

Attach an electrical schematic of this circuit and the datasheet for the motion sensor you're talking about. This is kind of a bullshit question and as posed does not describe a practical functioning circuit. Digital sensors signal through an electrical contact that if NO (normally open) is open/de-energized 0VDC when not triggered, or closed/energized +24VDC when triggered.

A sensor does not communicate over RS-232.

1. A digital sensor signal-wire is typically connected to a controller (like a PLC) input-terminal, and the controller provides +24VDC power to the digital sensor, and a seperate 0VDC potential common terminal if a 3-wire digital sensor.
2. controller converts the sensor input signal to the 8-bit binary format that the RS-232 interface can transmit to another nodes RS-232 interface
3. the RS-232 interface at the recieving node, your terminal, detects a voltage drop at the RxD as the start bit, and recieves the transmitted 8 bit byte by detecting the number voltage blips in the communication interval that is determined by the baud rate setting.

RS-232 is a communication protocol between 2 systems that specifies which pins are used for "hardware handshaking" when 1 node wants to send data to another node.
The data pulses are transmitted from the TxD "transmit data" pin by the transmitting node, and if a recieving node is connected with a null-modem cable, the pulses are recieved at receiving node's RxD "recieve data" pin.

Sofware handshaking is done by using the TxD & RxD transmit & recieve pins but sensors generally do not use it, its slower and if signal is dropped after handshake neither side is aware.

The DB9 9-pin connector is most commonly used, but a 7-pin RJ45 Ethernet connector can be used when communication is one-way because the transmitting node doesn't need a CTR clear to recieve pin, nor does the recieving node need the RTS request to send pin.

Applying the tutorial to your example, your PC will have both a DTE Data Terminal Equipment port and a DCE Data Communications Equipment port mapped to your model interface card

The "format" the data is transmitted on the TxD pin#2 of the sending-sensor, & recieved on the RxD pin#3 of the recieving terminal,  is 8 bits of binary.
which the sender-sensor (in your example) is changing the voltage-potential between 0 volts DC to +24 volts DC

How to "read" the data?
If you had really fast eyes you could use a volt-meter to watch the voltage-potential change from - to + by connecting the black electrode to GND pin#5 & red electrode to TxD on pin#3 on the sending node.
Or do the same thing with an osciloscope and set your X-axis for the baud-rate time-interval